# How to Merge mutiple keys with different conditions

Tags: xslt

I have a problem on grouping multiple keys based on a criteria .

I have 2 records in XML. Document 1 and Document 2

The objective is to create a table with 2 sections. Same, Change.

Elements which have same rec_no, part_no, ext_qty which are there in both documents should come in the subsection Same. 
Element which are there in both documents but with change in  rec_no, part_no, ext_qty should come under change subsection.

Now for this I created different keys on this conditions. Now my problem is how to group the keys to get the results.

Here is the output table with my comments.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Section RecNo   Desc    Doc-1 Qty   Doc-2 Qty   Total
---------------------------------------------------------
Same    111     Desc1   1           1            100

---------------------------------------------------------
Same Total                                      100
---------------------------------------------------------
Change  222     Desc2   2           3           500
Change  333     Desc3   3           3           600
Change  444     Desc4   6           4           600
---------------------------------------------------------
Change Total                                    1300
---------------------------------------------------------
Grand Total                                     1400
---------------------------------------------------------
```

My XML is :

```
<Logia>
  <DocHeader>
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <part_no>111</part_no>
                <rec_no>aaa</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <ext_qty>1</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <part_no>222</part_no>
                <rec_no>bbb</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc2</desc>
                <ext_qty>2</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <part_no>333</part_no> 
                <rec_no>ccc</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc3</desc>
                <ext_qty>3</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <part_no>444</part_no>
                <rec_no>ddd</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc4</desc>
                <ext_qty>6</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>

        </Document>
        <Document>
            <Downto>
                <part_no>111</part_no>
                <rec_no>aaa</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc1</desc>
                <ext_qty>1</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>  
            <Downto>
                <part_no>222</part_no>
                <rec_no>bbb</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc3</desc>
                <ext_qty>3</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto> 
            <Downto>
                <part_no>333</part_no>
                <rec_no>bbb</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc3</desc>
                <ext_qty>3</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>100.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>
            <Downto>
                <part_no>444</part_no>
                <rec_no>ddd</rec_no>
                <desc>Desc4</desc>
                <ext_qty>4</ext_qty>
                <mat_cost>400.00</mat_cost>
            </Downto>                        
         </Document>
  </DocHeader>
</Logia>
```

and my XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="MAT1PARTKEY" match="Document[1]/Downto" use="part_no" />
<xsl:key name="MAT2PARTKEY" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="part_no" />
<xsl:key name="MAT1RECKEY" match="Document[1]/Downto" use="rec_no" />
<xsl:key name="MAT2RECKEY" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="rec_no" />
<xsl:key name="MAT1QTYKEY" match="Document[1]/Downto" use="ext_qty" />
<xsl:key name="MAT2QTYKEY" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="ext_qty" />
<xsl:key name="MAT1COSTKEY" match="Document[1]/Downto" use="mat_cost" />
<xsl:key name="MAT2COSTKEY" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="mat_cost" />

<xsl:key name="MATERIALBYPARTNO" match="Document/Downto" use="part_no" />

<xsl:template match="/Logia/DocHeader">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- header -->
        <tr>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>PartNo</th>
            <th>RecNo</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Doc-1 Qty</th>
            <th>Doc-2 Qty</th>   
            <th> Total</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- same -->
        <xsl:variable name="same" select="Document[1]/Downto[key('MAT2RECKEY', part_no]" />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$same">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Same</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:variable name="same-total" select="sum($same/mat_cost)" />    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Same Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$same-total"/></th>
        </tr>       
        <!-- change -->
        <xsl:variable name="change" select="Document[1]/Downto[not(key('MAT2RECKEY', rec_no ))]" />  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$change">
            <xsl:with-param name="section">Change</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:variable name="change-total" select="sum($change/mat_cost)" />    
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Change Total</td>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$change-total"/></th>
        </tr>

        <!-- grand total -->
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">Grand Total</th>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$same-total + $add-total + $delete-total"/></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Downto">
    <xsl:param name="section"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('MATERIALBYPARTNO', part_no)[1])">
      <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$section"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="part_no"/></td>  
          <td><xsl:value-of select="rec_no"/></td>            
          <td><xsl:value-of select="desc"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('MAT1PARTKEY', part_no)/ext_qty)"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('MAT2PARTKEY', part_no)/ext_qty)"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('MATERIALBYPARTNO', part_no)/mat_cost)"/></td>
      </tr>   

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Keys by quantity and cost are useless.

b. You can construct key of any complexity. In you case:

```
<xsl:key name="downtoByKeyFields" match="Downto" use="concat(rec_no, '||',  part_no, '||', ext_qty)"/>
```

and when you call this key, you should do the same:

```
key('downtoByKeyFields', concat(rec_no, '||',  part_no, '||', ext_qty))
```

This key will return all Downto fields that have the given combination of rec_no, part_no, ext_qty values.

p.s. This should work if none of this values contain || :)

---

Main idea:

```
<xsl:key name="MATERIAL2BYKEY" match="Document[2]/Downto" use="concat(rec_no, '||',  part_no, '||', ext_qty)" />

...

<xsl:variable name="same" select="Document[1]/Downto[key('MATERIAL2BYKEY', concat(rec_no, '||',  part_no, '||', ext_qty))]" />  

...

<xsl:variable name="change" select="Document[1]/Downto[not(key('MATERIAL2BYKEY', concat(rec_no, '||',  part_no, '||', ext_qty)))]" />
```

It's pretty straightforward: *Elements which have same rec_no, part_no, ext_qty* in terms of keys is the key that matches all elements with the same rec_no, part_no, ext_qty. We need to specify expression that will tell xslt transformer that two elements have same rec_no, part_no, ext_qty - concat(rec_no, 'some separator', part_no, 'some separator', ext_qty), for example.

Comment: Thanks Rudolph. I tried this, but i am getting Records with change in quantity in Same records. || symbol denotes "or" condition right. Should i use + for "and" condition

Comment: No, || is just a string separator, you can use any chars not expected in rec_no, part_no and ext_qty.

Comment: Excellent Rudolph. Now i got it. Thank you so much. Appreciate it